# Unity file 404 errors when running virtual controllers

Tags: airconsole

I currently have the file structure below in my assets folder in Unity.

`├───AirConsole
│   ├───examples
│   │   ├───basic
│   │   │   └───Materials
│   │   └───pong
│   │       ├───materials
│   │       ├───scripts
│   │       └───sprites
│   ├───extras
│   ├───plugins
│   │   ├───Android
│   │   ├───iOS
│   │   ├───Newtonsoft.Json
│   │   │   ├───Bson
│   │   │   ├───Converters
│   │   │   ├───Linq
│   │   │   ├───Schema
│   │   │   ├───Serialization
│   │   │   └───Utilities
│   │   └───x86_64
│   │       └───WebView.bundle
│   │           └───Contents
│   │               ├───MacOS
│   │               └───Resources
│   ├───resources
│   └───scripts
│       └───editor
└───WebPlayerTemplates
    |---controller.html
    ├───airconsole-controls
    │   ├───button
    │   ├───ctrl-generator
    │   ├───dpad
    │   ├───examples
    │   ├───joystick
    │   ├───rate-limiter
    │   ├───shake-detecor
    │   ├───swipe-analog
    │   ├───swipe-digital
    │   └───swipe-pattern
    ├───controller
    │   ├───js
    │   ├───libs
    │   ├───styles
    │   └───templates
    └───__MACOSX
        └───controller
            ├───js
            ├───libs
            ├───styles
            └───templates`

When I start the unity project, I get 404 errors for the following requests.

`GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/button/button.css 
controller.html:10 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/dpad/dpad.css 
controller.html:12 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/styles/styles.css 
controller.html:13 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/styles/controls.css 
controller.html:56 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/libs/handlebars-v4.0.5.js 
controller.html:59 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/libs/airconsole_view_manager.js 
controller.html:62 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/dpad/dpad.js 
controller.html:66 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/js/controller_generator.js 
controller.html:61 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/button/button.js 
controller.html:64 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/swipe-digital/swipe-digital.js 
controller.html:63 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/airconsole-controls/swipe-analog/swipe-analog.js 
controller.html:67 GET http://192.168.56.1:7842/controller/js/main.js`
Do I have a misunderstanding on how I should structure my project so that airconsole can find the proper files? or am I missing projects. I am on version 1.6. Also the controller.html file is sitting inside the WebPlayerTemplates. I have all of the airconsole client side stuff in that folder because if I dont I get about 100 compile errors due to syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the files used by your controller.html have to be in the folder: Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole

The Unity guide is a great place to [start](https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/unity)

Or you can just download the free project from the [asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/42776) and play around with it.

Also something that caught us out: don't put your custom controller.html file you want to use in Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole, this controller.html is overwritten by the Airconsole object. Rather put your controller.html file elsewhere and drag it onto the "Controller Html" property in the inspector of the Airconsole object.

Comment: Yeah I realized I looked past the documentation there. I had it in web Player templates. Also that was the next issue I ran into and now that is also solved!